# Maintaining model relations from old DB into Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activerecord, activerecord-import

I'm taking exported CSV files from an old File Maker Pro DB and redoing in Rails/ActiveRecord. I'm using the Gem 'ActiveRecord-import' to import the CSV files. There are old relations that I've created an attribute for in my new UML creation.

Question: How do I maintain those relations in my new Join tables which will be used for future CRUD? For example: I have Company and Projects. Company has_many Projects through CompanyProject. I'm doing all the importing in my Seed file. If I have an attribute named `old_company_id` and `old_project_id`, how do I use those old Id's in my new schema to maintain the relationship?

Comment: Isn't the answer that you assign them to your CompanyProject? Or is there something more interesting going on?

Comment: Is it really that simple? Like `company_id: old_company_id`? I was concerned that there would be duplicate ids made on the creation of new objects. I suppose the Rails magic will see that there is already an id with that number and move on?